# Why is it that when I use an int from a separate class, it gives me random numbers?

Tags: c++, class, int

I'm relatively new to coding,I know the basics of Java and C++ so far, but I am trying to organize my cod a bit more and speed up compile time a little. So far I've only figured out how to use functions from other classes. I'm self-learning everything so if anyone could show me an example using the code I've posted, that would be perfect. Feel free to explain it like you're talking to a child because these Header files are VERY confusing to me.

test.h:

```
#pragma once
class test
{
public:

    //functions
    test();
    void part2();

    //variables

    int varA;
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "test.h"

int varA = 10;

test::test()
{
    cout << "this is the test main function" << endl;

}

void test::part2(){
    cout << "you got to part 2, also, Variable A is " << varA << " when it's in test.cpp" << endl;
}
```

ConsoleApplication1

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    test objectA;
    objectA.part2();
    cout << "variable A is " << objectA.varA << "when it's in CA1.cpp" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

here is the console's output

```
this is the test main funtion
you got to part 2, also, Variable A is -858993460 when it's in CA1.cpp
variable A is -858993460 in CA1.cpp
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

EDIT: So can I only get the varA that I'm declaring in the header in the test::test constructor? I tested this way, and it worked, it did return 10. however, if i want to use the same variable in the header/class, in a different function apart from the constructor, it gives me the gibberish again. The only way I can seem to use it, is if I create a global variable named something else, and use that. this wouldn't be practical if I needed to refer to it later like in an 'if-statement'.

What I'm trying to do is, make varA in test.cpp, and refer/use it inside of ConsoleApplication1.cpp.

Comment: Please get a book regarding C/C++

Comment: Folks, snarky comments don't help.

Comment: @isanae It's not snarky, OP has a basic misunderstanding of how to initialize member variables, a C++ book would help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
int varA = 10;
```

creates a *new* variable named `varA` which is independent of its homonym in class `test` instances.

Primitive types, such as your `int varA` in the definition of class `test` are not initialized by default, hence the `-858993460` value you obtain. You can set an initial value in the constructor of test:

```
test::test()
   : varA(10)
{}
```

Or inside the class declaration in C++11:

```
class test
{
    // …
    int varA = 10;
}
```

Comment: `homonyme` is a no good expression

Comment: So can I only get the varA that I'm declaring in the header in the test::test constructor? I tested this way, and it worked, it did return10. however, if i want to use the same variable in the header, in a different function apart from the constructor, it gives me the gibberish again. The only way I can seem to use it, is if I create a global variable named something else, and use that. this wouldn't be practical if I needed to refer to it later like in an 'if-statement'.
Because what I want to do is, make varA in test.cpp, and refer/use it inside of ConsoleApplication1.cpp.

Comment: Each `test` instance has its own copy, with a different value, of `varA`. If you *really* want them to have the same value, you can use a global variable, or a `static` variable. For the latter, you can declare its storage and set a default value with `int test::varA = 10;` in you test.cpp.

Answer (score 2):

The `varA` you define on top of `test.cpp` is different than the one in the `test` class. It is also never used, because inside the various member functions, the member `varA` has priority.

If you want to initialize `test::varA` to 10, do it in the constructor:

```
test::test()
    : varA(10)
{
    cout << "this is the test main class" << endl;
}
```

You can get rid of the global `varA` in test.cpp completely.